# Compiling glfw application mingw

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw, mingw

I am trying to compile a glfw application on mingw.
I am using 64 bit windows and 32bit mingw compiler And I have downloaded 32 bit binaries from http://www.glfw.org/download.html I am trying do by linking to libraries as follows

```
-lglfw3 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32
```

But I get the following error

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libglfw3.a(init.c.obj):init.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `__ms_
vsnprintf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Looks like the top Google results for "__ms__vsnprintf" [are](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=__ms__vsnprintf) about people with MinGW having similar issues compiling things. Are any of them similar enough to derive a solution? What compilation instructions are you following for GLFW?